# How to generate table scripts with data in Toad for Oracle - 9.7.2

Tags: oracle, toad

I wanna create a script for table that should include

1. Create Table statement
2. Data in the table
3. Sequence in the table(Only sequence code)
4. And Trigger associated to it

I have added Sequence and trigger for auto increment ID, I searched but I couldn't get enough answers for Sequence in trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you, partially.

In order to get `CREATE TABLE` statement, choose that table and on right-hand side of the screen navigate to the "Script" tab - there it is. Apart from `CREATE TABLE`, it contains some more statements (such as `ALTER TABLE` in order to add constraints, `CREATE INDEX` and your number 4 - `CREATE TRIGGER`).

As of the sequence: it is a separate object, which is not related to any table. One sequence can be used to provide unique numbers for many tables, so - I'm not sure what is it that you are looking for.

In order to get data from that table, right-click table name; in menu choose "Export data" >> "Insert statements". That'll create bunch of `INSERT INTO` commands. That's OK if table is small; for large ones, you'll get old before it finishes.

The last sentence leads to another suggestion: why would you want to do it that way? A proper option is to **export** that table, using either Data Pump or the *Original* EXP utility.

**[EDIT]**

After you insert data "as is" (i.e. no changes in ID column values), disable trigger and run additional update. If we suppose that sequence name is MY_SEQ (create it the way you want it, specifying its start value etc.), it would be as simple as

```
update your_table set id = my_seq.nextval;
```

Once it is done, enable the trigger so that it fires for newly added rows.

Comment: Insert statement creates with existing unique ID, I execute trigger before Inserting data why its taking existing Unique ID instead of generating new? What should i do if wanna create new Unique Id while running the insert statement?